# How can I diagnose motherboard issues?

Tags: memory, cpu, crash, reboot, computer-building

It's my first time asking a question on this forum, I hope someone with experience in building PC's is able to help me here.

I recently bought all the components for my first pc build. After assembling, however, it seems that it's constantly rebooting - Initially, I couldn't even install Windows.

My specifications are as follows:

- Motherboard: MSI B550M Pro-VDH WiFi
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- SSD: Crucial P1 NVMe M.2 SSD
- RAM: Patriot Viper 16GB 2x8GB DDR4
- GPU:Sapphire Pulse AMD Radeon RX 5600XT
- PSU: AeroCool Integrator 500W
- CPU Cooler: be quiet! Pure Rock Slim

I've tried as many things as I can think of in order to diagnose the problem. My first thought was that there was a RAM issue. I tried swapping my RAM sticks between DIMM slots A2 and B2, using the other DIMM slots A1 and B1 (not recommended by MSI), testing with a friend's RAM sticks that definitely work, and activating XMP profile 1 to increase memory clock speeds to the full 3200mhz. None of this solved the issue.

I also booted Memtest86 via UEFI USB to attempt a memory test. Curiously, I could remain in the configuration section for as long as I wanted but as soon as I started the test, and reached test 4 or 5 (Moving Inversions 8 bit pattern), it crashed and rebooted.

Moving on, I swapped the GPU for a smaller, older model in case the PSU wasn't supplying enough power to all my components. This made no difference. Note that throughout these tests, my CPU has remained cool - I don't believe overheating to be the issue, especially since installing windows shouldn't be a particularly strenuous task.

Later, I tried swapping my CPU with my friend's older model that I know to work - A Ryzen 5 2600 - in case the CPU was causing the problem. This time the memory test ran fine and I was able to install Windows successfully. As I was downloading drivers, and contacting the eBay seller asking for a new CPU (sure that the one I was sold was faulty) my pc suddenly rebooted again. :(

I find this to be pretty bizarre - An older, less efficient processor works for longer than a newer model but nonetheless my pc is still shutting down.

Is this a problem with the Motherboard? note that I've also flashed bios. How can I check for this and should I order a new one?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Do you know what "ESD" is? -> https://www.google.com/search?q=esd+wrist+strap+how+to+use   If YES: did you take any precautionary steps to avoid it?

Comment: Nope. I'll buy some wrist straps just in case though thanks. Can that really kill your parts though?

Comment: Absolutely, and it may affect more than one part in one go.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of faults are hard to diagnose.

One can guess at it being caused by ESD[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=esd%20wrist%20strap%20how%20to%20use), which can cause not only one but several components to get damage.
It may also show up "later", if the damage wasn't severe enough to cause immediate breakage. Compare to running over a garden water hose in such a way that it starts to leak. It still works, but will eventually have to be replaced.
Electronics can "leak" (internally) in a similar manner; causing (occasional) strange behavior, until a final breakage after some indefinite time.

The simplest form of preotection:
Wearing a wrist band that grounds your body to e.g. protective ground in your house power connectors. => [Google(wristband)](https://www.google.com/search?q=esd%20wrist%20strap%20how%20to%20use)

[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=esd%20wrist%20strap%20how%20to%20use) **E**lectro**S**tatic **D**ischarge
Generally you should expect electronics, especially computer related hardware, to be sensitive to high voltage spikes.
To avoid such you have to eliminate charge differences between your body and all the components you handle. These are the cause for the *snap* you occasionally can get as you touch e.g. a facuet.